# How do I extract every consecutive pair of lines at a time from a file efficiently?

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

I have a text file containing `n` lines of text in the following form:

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
.
.
.
line_n_minus_1
line_n
```

I wish to extract every consecutive pair of lines, (i.e `line_1` and `line_2`, `line_2` and `line_3` and so on, until `line_n_minus_1` and `line_n`), do something with each extracted pair, and keep doing this until `line_n_minus_1` and `line_n`. How would I go about doing this efficiently for large files?

This is what I had in mind:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
    for i in pairwise(list_of_lines):
         # do something with the pair tuple i
```

However, I hate to be relying on `readlines()`, since I'm potentially going to work with big text files. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `readlines`, create a generator so you don't have to load the whole file to memory:

```
.
.
.
with open('a.txt') as f:
    list_of_lines = (line for line in f)
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.